# Calculate total monthly average price using MapReduce in python

Tags: python, mapreduce

How should I calculate total average monthly price from the following data? It is from daily stock price of each company.

```
MSFT,3/18/2019,117.57
GOOG,3/18/2019,1184.26
AMZN,3/18/2019,1742.15
...
```

And the expect result should be like:

```
3, 1029.2323
4, 1071.7411
5, 1063.8184
6,  982.8590
```

I would like to take advantage of the following MapReduce code in Python.

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
data = line.split(',')
if (data[0] == 'MSFT'):
    print(data[1] + ',' + data[2])
```

I tried started with editing the map function as follows:

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
data = line.split(',')
if (data[1][:1] == '3'):
    print(data[1] + ',' + data[2])
```

Maybe I need to write a loop for calculate each month's map function?
For the reduce function I am stuck so any hints or solutions are welcome. Thank you.

Comment: how can you calculate the monthly average using a single day data? I think you need to provide some rules to do calculations here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'r confusing yourself. Simply calculate the average by taking in the data and adding them up. Then take the data you just got and divide them. For instance:

```
microsoft_monthly_sales = 7335856
microsoft_monthly_profit = 9585838122847

google_monthly_sales = 7947478
google_monthly_profit = 548584894544

amazon_monthly_sales = 6635625
amazon_monthly_profit = 99484858390

#Now add the profits up and divide by three(since their are 3 companies that we are working with
first_profit = microsoft_monthly_profit + google_monthly_profit + amazon_monthly_profit
final_profit = first_profit / 3
```

You can also add inputs to change the profits and sales easily. I would've done it myself here but I'm running a bit late.